# How to get address from postal code?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a registration form. I would like to query how to get full address from a postal code.

This is what I intend to do.

1. User key in postal code
2. User click on button called "auto fetch"
3. Full address get loaded in to text field.

Note: address need to be global.

I researched online and found out that this can actually be done in using Google Maps API, am I right? I am confused because what Google Maps API does with is latitude and longitude. How do I incorporate postal code in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Jim and Mukul have said is correct.

In the UK for instance, a postcode is only a "routing instruction" which in the vast majority of cases is sufficient to identify the thoroughfare or dependent-thoroughfare. However, if coupled with a DPS (Delivery Point Suffix - which no consumer needs to know or should care about) it can identify an address, but this again won't work in all cases since a major block of flats may have several flats with identical DPS's.

In the UK it's important to note that a postcode is a *routing instruction* for delivery purposes and (although it can be in some sense) isn't technically a geographical location.

In terms of lat/lon to get an address, it depends on the accuracy of the data the system is based on, as some are only 100m, 50m, 25m, 10m etc...  (so you might get a house in the street, or a house a couple of doors away etc...)

There are addressing solutions out there, that given a postal code will then return a list of known addresses (and also lat/lon coords for it (to a certain accuracy))... Some provide an online API which can be used - but the majority of those services are paid for, and some are actually quite expensive.

Comment: +1 for explanation of postal code as a rounting system to increase delivery efficiency. It carries the same purpose here in india. To manage and route packets to area specific offices.

Answer (score 1):

There is no commonly-used postal code that resolves down to a specific delivery point (US DPBC and equivalents in other countries *may* do so but they are not something a postal customer knows about or would be able to provide).

The best you can do from a postal code is populate the City and State/Province.

Answer (score 1):

To locate THE location /delivery point you need longitude n latitude with Google Maps API, with post code you can locate city/area to the best

Comment: The postal code is designed that way. it does not point a location, it points an arean/province. So you can locate an area/province with that.

Comment: postal code is to locate the area, does that mean we can't get the address from it, like our blk # street name etc?

Comment: It all comes down to how the govt has laid out postal codes. it defines a street/area/district etc.  The askee is asking about having a delivery point from postal code. Generally a postal code specifies an area.  many blocks/streets n houses share a pin code. You very easily use the postal code to mark out an area but not a delivery point. To mark a point on a map you are going to need its coordinates. many blocks n street share a postal code, u can get the area name from postal code not a block or street. A postal code just doesnt carries that information.

Comment: Have it like this , from postal code is defined for an area. You can get higher level of info from it but not go any level lower it is not defined for. A postal code says about area, from that you can get city,state,country,continent but not the block or street or house number. Regards

Answer (score 1):

In the UK the information you require costs upward of £375 per anum. In countries where this data is available will probably involve a cost. I would imagine that not all countries have this facitity.

The best you can obtain from Google and [Geonames](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/)etc is the centroid of the post code/zip

Comment: I thought it was about £4k+ if you wanted the complete PAF (not including new builds etc..) - short of using something like QuickAddress (which I think got bought by Experian at some point)

Comment: See http://www.poweredbypaf.com/end-user/products/paf-raw-data/

Comment: what do you mean by centroid of postal code/zip? is there no way we can get the address via google map through postal code?

Comment: As post and zip codes cover an area the coordiates are  located within the area. As the area is rarely a circle the term centroid is used instead of centre see. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid .In practice the actual coordinates may not lie on the centroid, but the term is generally used. As stated earlier google maps only give a location within an area.